# Order Summary creation failed

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, connect-api

On our project we have order creation for logged user and for guest. We would like to transform order to OrderSummary but it fails. In Apex we use ConnectApi.OrderSummaryCreation.createOrderSummary but we receive errors:

For Logged in user: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY - insufficient access rights on cross-reference id For Guest: Insufficient Privileges: This feature is not currently enabled for this user.

The code works when calling it from Developer Console.

We also tried Record-Triggered Flow because it runs default in system mode but it also failed showing the same errors.

Does anyone have experience on that and have any solution ?